# Is there a way to create a feed from any webpage?

Tags: webapp-rec, feeds

There's a web page that updates once in a while and I would very like to be notified when it is updated, preferably using some sort of feed (such as RSS). Unfortunately, that website itself does not publish any sort of feed for that page.

Is there any service which can provide a feed to an external website? E.g. something that will occasionally probe a specific webpage and if it has changed from the last time, publish a new entry in a dedicated feed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use [page2rss](http://page2rss.com/).google reader used to provide this service , but they have recently turned off this feature.

Comment: This works exceptionally well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader). [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader) can follow changes of any website. See [this blog](http://googlereader.blogspot.com/2010/01/follow-changes-to-any-website.html) for more details.

> At Google we're always looking for ways to take advantage of work being done in other parts of the organization. So when a team approached us with a way to follow changes from websites without feeds, we jumped at the opportunity. Post by Liza Ma, Product Manager.
> Feeds make it easy to follow updates to all kinds of webpages, from blogs to news sites to Craigslist queries, but unfortunately not all pages on the web have feeds. Today we're rolling out a change in Google Reader that lets you create a custom feed to track changes on pages that don't have their own feed.
> These custom feeds are most useful if you want to be alerted whenever a specific page has been updated. For example, if you wanted to follow Google.org's latest products, just type "http://www.google.org/products.html" into Reader's "Add a subscription" field. Click "create a feed", and Reader will periodically visit the page and publish any significant changes it finds as items in a custom feed created just for that page.
> [image]
> Here are some more example feeds for sites without feeds that you could follow:
>
> - [Macy's - special offers](http://www1.macys.com/catalog/index.ognc?CategoryID=27416&PageID=117753556101860&kw=Special%20Offers) [[view in Reader](http://www.google.com/reader/view/#stream/webfeed%2F8765363390147717237)]
> - [NYU Computer Science homepage](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/) [[view in Reader](http://www.google.com/reader/view/#stream/webfeed%2F12825487959154103617)]
> - [Zillow.com homepage](http://zillow.com/) [[view in Reader](http://www.google.com/reader/view/#stream/webfeed%2F7213111791824341699)]
>
> We provide short snippets of page changes to help you quickly decide if the page is worth revisiting and we're working on improving the quality of these snippets. If you don't want Google to crawl or create feeds for a specific site, site owners can [opt-out](http://www.google.com/support/reader/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=172963).
> If you have a feed-less page you've been dying to follow, sign in to Google Reader and try it out for yourself. As always, if you have any feedback, please visit our [official help forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/reader?hl=en) or our [Twitter account](http://twitter.com/googlereader).

**Update:**
**Sorry this feature is currently not available.** See [this blog](http://googlereader.blogspot.com/2010/09/turning-off-track-changes-feature.html).

Comment: Google Reader has been discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

[Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) is a very good, and very powerful option for this, although the learning curve can be steep.

Comment: Yahoo Pipes has been discontinued.

Answer (score -1):

[FeedYes](http://www.feedyes.com/) does this

Comment: Interesting, though (1) looks like it's appropriate only for web pages which are themselves composed of a series of links, such as blogs; and (2) seems to cost ~30$ per year :\